# Does the Google-Eclipse plugin autogenerate war directory contents?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, war, google-eclipse-plugin

I just created my first **Web Application Project** using the Google-Eclipse plugin. Amongst other artifacts, it autogenerated a `war/` directory with several subdirectories and many files, including:

```
war/
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
            <Lots of JARs here>
        web.xml
        appengine-web.xml
        etc.
```

Several times now I've cleared out certain parts of this `war/` directory (messing around with buildscripts and other Google-Eclipse plugin features - this is just a test/temp project for getting used to the plugin), and they magically reappear at some point in the future.

I'm wondering if, because I set this up as a Web Application Project (and it is thus managed by the Google-Eclipse plugin), is the plugin trying to preserve the structure of the `war/`, and as such, continuing to auto-generate any missing files?

If so, why? Exactly (which files/directories) what is it trying to preserve? Can I disable it?

And if not, then I obviously have something else going on here. In which case, has anybody else ever experienced this with the Google-Eclipse plugin, or just Eclipse in general? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin only updates war/lib directory by adding dependencies. Actually it just copies jar files when you switch to a another version of Google App Engine SDK.

Comment: Thanks @Antonio (+1) - I knew I wasn't crazy! Is there any way to disable this? I have an external Ant/Ivy build file that pulls dependencies down from my remote Ivy repo and copies them into `gen/lib/main`. Later on in the build, JARs are copied from `gen/lib/main` into `war/WEB-INF/lib` and then the WAR is packaged. I'd like this `war/WEB-INF/lib` to always be empty before I perform the copy from `gen/lib/main`!

Comment: why don't you create an ant task to delete files inside the folder prior copy from gen/lib/main?

Comment: I could certainly do that, but it feels ugly and unnecessary. The plugin should have a way to disable automated features like this "copy jars" business.

Answer (score 1):

This should  not be a problem.

War folder is the exploded package that later on you need to deploy to Google App Engine.

When you build or deploy file to GAE, this folder will be re-created/updated, and it contains the newly compiled jar and the necessary libs.

Read [this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29)

Comment: Thanks @Rudy (+1), I'm aware of what a WAR is, and understand that the WAR directory is an exploded WAR directory. I'm just asking how to disable this feature.

Comment: I'm afraid no - if you are using the Eclipse Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

War folder contains the generated javascript files which are deployed to the app engine.